# C# - How to use variables within other functions

Tags: c#, windows, forms, function

I am trying to use the variable rand from the `Rnd` function within the `BtnRed_Click` function. The return does not do anything. And if I change the parameters for the `Rnd` function I get an error.

Here's my code.

```
namespace ColourPick_EDP2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int RandomNum;
        int counter = 60;
        int rand; 

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void BtnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BtnStart.Visible = false;
            Tmr.Tick += new EventHandler(tmr_Tick);
            Tmr.Start();
            TbxDisplay.Text = counter.ToString();

           Random rnd = new Random();
           RandomNum = rnd.Next(0, 7);
           Rnd(RandomNum);   
        }

        private void tmr_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            counter--;
            if (counter == 0)
            {
                Tmr.Stop();
            }
            TbxDisplay.Text = counter.ToString();

        }

        private int Rnd(int rand)
        {
            int rand = rand;
            switch(rand)
            {

                case 1:
                    this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Purple;
                    break;
                case 6:
                    this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Orange;
                    break;
            }
            return rand;
        }


        private void BtnRed_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (rand == 1)
            {
                lblScore.Text += 10; 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: Delete this line in `Rnd()`: `int rand = rand;`. What were you trying to accomplish by putting that line there?

Comment: *"if i change the parameters for Rnd function i get an error."* Change them how? What error do you get? If you want help with something, provide enough information for us to guess what you did and what happened when you did it.

Comment: *"The return does not do anything"* -- You're not using the value it returns, and the return value is exactly the value you pass in anyhow. Do you understand what `return` means?

Answer (score 0):

Your not actually doing anything with the value of rand in the RND method, so just use RandomNum. which probably should be randomNum instead of RandomNum

```
    private void BtnRed_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (RandomNum == 1)
        {
            lblScore.Text += 10; 
        }
    }
```

Comment: @CharlieWills ok, thanks. Please mark as the answer if that fixes it for you.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that what you really want to do is call a function and have it do a few things:

1. Choose a new random integer colourValue between 1 and 6
2. Set the background colour of your form
3. Return the colorValue to the calling function so you can use it.

Here is what I suggest you do:

Declare your  random number generator at class level rather than inside BtnStart_Click

```
Random  randomiser = new Random()
```

Call your function something that describes what it does like ChooseNewColor rather than Rnd. You can give it a parameter if you like, perhaps indicating how many colours it should choose between. Here is a suitable declaration:

```
private int ChooseNewColor(int numberOfColors)
{
    int colorValue = randomiser.Next(1, numberOfColors +1)
    switch(colorValue)
    {
        case 1:
            this.BackColor =       etc…  

    }
    return colorValue;
}
```

Now for a call to the function

`currentColor = ChooseNewColor(MaxColorValue);`

This assumes that MaxColorValue is a constant representing the highest color value (probably 6 in your code) and  its output is to be stored in an integer variable called currentColor which has already been declared.

Comment: It may help you to understand that when you call a function the _values_ of the arguments are passed in and the parameters are given those values. So, in this case, the argument is MaxColorValue which has the _value_ 6. Now, within the function itself, the parameter numberOfColors is assigned the value 6. The return statement returns the _value_ of colorValue which is then assigned to currentColor on the calling line.